# Cannot build prod after angular 5 to 7 update, terser error

Tags: angular-cli, updates

I had an Angular-cli project with Angular 5.2. that I updated to Angular 7.2.3. Everything is ok, `ng serve`, `ng test`, but when I want to `ng build --prod` I get errors

I followed the guide (https://update.angular.io/) step by step

Here are the errors :

```
ERROR in runtime.82c6613acef8f7246fe8.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at minify (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:175:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/worker.js:13:40)
    at handle (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:51:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:783:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
ERROR in main.ae88265d57a522e8fef6.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at minify (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:175:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/worker.js:13:40)
    at handle (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:51:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:783:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
ERROR in polyfills.93cd0d5603ed4cb47cce.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at minify (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:175:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/worker.js:13:40)
    at handle (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:51:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:783:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
ERROR in styles.dcc46c6ff0d6be4a76ad.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at minify (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:175:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/worker.js:13:40)
    at handle (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/nicolasgarin/Desktop/afreecom/front/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:51:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:783:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
```

I have no clue about what's wrong and google didn't helped me neither

Comment: Same issue as what R. Richards links to above. What I did to fix can be found there. I thought I had broken something, but it was a Terser update that is broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a problem with the current version of terser, by now, you should set the version to 3.14.1 in your package.json as follows: `"terser": "3.14.1",`

If you have `"terser": "^3.14.1",` by sure to remove the `^`.

Comment: Thank you it was indeed the terser version in cause

Comment: @kazu I don't see terser in my package.json file but it's present in package.lock.json, should I just install it so it gets updated in my package.lock.json file?

Comment: @ImmadHamid You might want to do `npm i terser@3.14.1 --saveDev`.

Comment: Yea did the same earlier and the issue was fixed. Anyway thanks alot man...